# How to get bar chart data label to display both value and percent (of total) in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, bar-chart, stacked-chart, column-chart

In a 100% stacked bar chart, how can I get the data label to display BOTH the value AND the percent of total?  Example: 129 (60.3%)

This is displayed in the tooltip when you hover over the bar, but not visible on the bar itself.

Example here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qpro5WMBxOljwshoDFXsqC5_XFz-aF8dlfgMxdCINp4/edit#gid=796957633

Comment: I dont think adding multiple data labels is possible. However, you could create your custom label by inserting a  new row/column with the text or formula you want to display for each data point (for example one cell value would be ```129 (60.3%)``` which you could obtain with the formula ```= C4&" ("&ROUND(C4*100/($C4+$C5+$C6),1)&"%)"```). but you would need to add this extra row/column of data label. Would you be interested in a solution with this workaround?

Comment: Yes, I think this might work for me.  I will attempt this.

Comment: This works!  Had to add an annotations column for each set of data labels.

Answer (score 0):

## Workaround

Unfortunately, at the moment of this answer it is not possible to add multiple data labels. However, you can create you own label by inserting an [annotations](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9085344) column next to each data point. The content of these annotation columns would be your desired label. Then you would just need to add these labels as described in the reference I just shared.

In your case it would look like `129 (60.3%)` which you could obtain from the following Google Sheets formula : `= C4&" ("&ROUND(C4*100/($C4+$C5+$C6),1)&"%)")`.